Causes of extreme seasons on an Earth-like planet such that humans need to migrate
I am thinking of an Earth-like planet that has extreme seasons (temperature) such that the humans (or other lifeforms) living there need to systematically migrate (probably twice per year) from one side/hemisphere of the planet to the other to survive.
What are some plausible causes for the extreme variations in temperature?
Think: stable and chaotic eras in Three-Body problem but more predictable.
Amplification
With regards to @L.Dutch's comment: this planet has likely been colonized by humans. In other words, life need not have evolved on the planet, only sustained by its conditions.

Make it a twin sun system, where the second smaller sun orbits in a high curve, orthogonal to the ecliptic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic. Its moderate on the north side, until the 2nd sun comes up every half year..
Or a moon, hyper reflective that goes in a very strange ellipse orbit around the world, reflecting additional light upon one hemisphere or the other.

I doubt such a system would be stable long enough to allow evolution of life.

Will update my question to stipulate that this planet may have been colonized by humans. It is not necessary for life to have originated on the planet itself.

@L.Dutch How about we negotiate down? No 2nd sun, just a moon, coated in reflective material, in a strange, slow orbit, that gives one half more light reflected?

@L.Dutch I may add an diamond asteroid belt, but thats my final offer, im cutting my own throat with this :D

The seasons on Earth are due to the tilt of the axis of rotation. The larger the tilt, the larger the seasonal difference. So, tilt the axis more.
A big problem with this type of change is the need for enough space connecting the landforms so that people can migrate. (See the traffic jams when people are trying to get out of Houston before a hurricane.) If people can't migrate, then they will invent ways to survive the harsh times in the different seasons - learning to live in snow or surviving the desert times. We will have different living conditions and clothing for the different seasons.
